# JBOSS EAP 6 blocked to call ejb method after asynchronous method

Tags: java, multithreading, jboss7.x

I have a stateless bean that insert some data using asynchronous method of other bean ( local injection). This data insertion takes a time , so I do not wait to finish for this operation. After this data insertion, I am calling another method of same bean. When I put a debug point to method, server waits for approximately 90 seconds to reach this point. May be Jboss waits for transaction to complete for asynchronous method. I do not know what is going on. .

```
   @Stateless
public class SimulationNodePersistenceBean implements SimulationNodePersistenceRemote, SimulationNodePersistenceLocal {
    @Resource
    SessionContext context;

    @EJB
    private SimulationResultGraphPersitenceBean graphPersistenceBean;

   @Asynchronous
   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
   private void addResultGraphsToDatabase(long id, Graph[] graphList) {

    ResultGraph paramGraph;
    ResultGraphPoint dataPoint;
    Graph graph;
    for (int i = 0; i < graphList.length; i++) {
        graph = graphList[i];
        paramGraph = new ResultGraph();

        try {
            graphPersistenceBean.persistGraph(paramGraph);
        } catch (Exception databaseException) {
            // TODO add error message to the contingency simulation messages
            // list
            logger.error("Error saving  ResultGraph:" + paramGraph);
        }
    }
    long duration = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    logger.debug("Graphs inserted to DB in (sec) :" + (duration / NANO_SECOND_CONVERSION_FACTOR));
}

    // @Asynchronous
public void persistSimulationResults(long contingencySimulationId, Graph[] graphList,
        List<AB> reiList) {
    if (graphList != null) {
        addResultGraphsToDatabase(contingencySimulationId, graphList);
    }
    if (reiList != null) {
    //another method
    }
    calculateContSimStability(contingencySimulationId);
}

    @Override
public void calculateSimIndex(long id) {

}
```

This is other bean called from main bean

```
 @Stateless
public class SimulationResultGraphPersitenceBean {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "DBService")
    private EntityManager em;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    @Asynchronous
    public void persistGraph(ResultGraph graph) throws SiGuardPersistenceException {
        try {
            ResultGraphService service = new ResultGraphService(em);
            service.create(graph);
            em.flush();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new PersistenceException("Error persisting graph", ex);
        }
    }
```

This is client calls main bean.This works asynchronously.

```
    getSimulationEJB().persistSimulationResults(id, tsaParser.getLstFile().getGraphArray());
```

After calling this method, I call another method of SimulationNodePersistenceBean.This method waits for some minutes.

```
getSimulationEJB().calculateSimIndex(contSimId);
```

I have created a thread dump using jstack. Actually I do not have this problem in Jboss As 6. I migrated my application to Jboss EAP 6. 4.  May be I need to make some configuration changes in configuration. But I do not know what should I do.

I checked thread dump. I did not find any thread in BLOCKING state. Should I look for other keywords?

Comment: If you can provide some sample code (or pseudo code) to illustrate your problem, it would be easily understood.

Comment: I have edited by adding code

Comment: I do not see the call to addResultGraphsToDatabase() method. My guess is that you are calling it from persistSimulationResults().

Before anything, be sure that it is indeed asynchronously called (as you are mixing the async and sync methods). You should remember to call the asynchronous method from the sessionContext. I just want to be sure that you are not doing this common mistake. Please take a look here: https://satishgopal.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/ejb-3-1-asynchronous-methods/ (look at the "Mixing sync and async" paragraph). Let me know.

Comment: I added code  for persistSİmulationResult. I think it is correct ?

Answer (score 2):

As I already pointed out in the comments, you are mixing the calling of Asynchronous and Synchronous methods. In your example, you are calling the addResultGraphsToDatabase method (Which is a Asynch method) from persistSimulationResults method (which is a synch method - since you have commented out the asynchronous annotation on top of it). Therefore, right now the addResultGraphsToDatabase method is behaving like a Synchronous method despite the Asynchronous annotation.

I am not sure if you took a look at the link that I posted in the comments but you need to call the Asynch method using the SessionContext. Something like this:

At the class level:

```
@Inject
SessionContext ctx;
```

The, within the persistSimulationResults method:

```
ctx.addResultGraphsToDatabase
```

For a more detailed example, please take a look at the link I have posted in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Should I also define persistSimulationResult method as asynchronous method?  Because other method called from inside it should not work asynchronously

Comment: I have tried to call addResultGraphsToDatabase method using    context.getBusinessObject(SimulationNodePersistenceBean.class).addResultGraphsToDatabase(contingencySimulationId, graphList);. It throws illegalstateexception

Comment: Please post the first few lines of the stacktrace for me to be able to help you.